# Send an email when an alarm is cleared

Tags: email, thingsboard, alarms

I've been working with alarms/rules and the email plugin, but still couldn't figure out how to send an email when an alarm is cleared.

I did see that there are flags to be used in the "email plugin action", but don't understand how they work.

Has anybody figured out how to send a new email when an alarm is cleared?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use 'isClearedAlarm' in flag field so it will send the mail when an alarm is cleared.